# The type checker's behavior while pattern matching in Coq

Tags: coq

I'm trying to examine how the type checker works on the following function, but can't understand
how the type checker works in the second (the nested) `match` clause:

```
Definition plus_O_2 := 
(fix F (m : mynat) : m == plus m O :=
    match m as m0 with
      | O as m2 => myeq_refl O : m2 == plus m2 O
      | S x as m2 => ((match F x in (m0 == m1) return (S m0 == S m1) with
                        | myeq_refl x0 => myeq_refl (S x0)
                      end) : m2 == plus m2 O)
    end) : forall n : mynat, n == plus n O.
```

This is a function that provides proof that `forall n : mynat, n == plus n O`, where `mynat`, `==`, `plus` are self-defined natural numbers, equality, and addition:

```
Inductive mynat :=
| O
| S (x:mynat).

Fixpoint plus (a b:mynat) :=
match a with
| O => b
| S n => S (plus n b)
end.

Inductive myeq {X:Type} : X -> X -> Prop :=
| myeq_refl : forall x, myeq x x.

Notation "x == y" := (myeq x y)
                       (at level 70, no associativity)
                     : type_scope.
```

(The definition for `myeq` and the corresponding `Notation` statement was referenced from Software Foundations Vol.1, https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/ProofObjects.html).

What I'm trying to understand is how Coq manages to type check this function. Here's what I understand of now:

- `F` first receives `m`. It is expected to return a value of type `m == plus m O` (The proposition we want to show).
- `m` passes through pattern matching.

  - If `m` is `O` (meant to represent zero), it returns `myeq_refl O`.

    - `myeq_refl O` has type `O == O`. Meanwhile, from `F`'s definition, it is expected to have type `O == plus O O`. (My guess is that,) Coq compares these types while type checking, and notices that `plus O O` is equivalent to `O` by its definition, so it passes the type check.
  - If `m` is of form `S x`, a second pattern matching starts running.

    - `F x` will have the form `x == plus x O`. This structure is captured in the `in` clause, and the `return` clause specifies that the returning type will be `S x == S (plus x O)`.
    - (I don't understand what happens here)
- Since both patterns end up with the type `m == plus m O`, the function has the type `forall n : mynat, n == plus n O`.

---

Now, my questions are, what exactly happens with the type checker in where I wrote "I don't understand what happens here?" Particularly,

- In my understanding, as the `in` clause specifies, `F x` is expected to have the type `m0 == m1`. Meanwhile, the matching clause `myeq_refl x0` seems to have the type `x0 == x0`, where both sides are equal. Why does Coq's type checker match these two seemingly different types?
- After the match (after `=>`), the `match` clause outputs `myeq_refl (S x0)`, which should have type `S x0 == S x0`. Meanwhile, the `return` clause stipulates that the returning type should be `S m0 == S m1`, which in my understanding should be equivalent to `S x == S (plus x O)`. These types, at first glance, seem different. How does Coq find out that these types are in fact equivalent?

  - Particularly, the second type seems to have a more complicated structure than the original proposition we want to show, `n == plus n O`, which should mean that Coq should not immediately be able to find that this is in fact equivalent to `n == n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The occurences of `m0` and `m1` inside the clause `in m0 == m1` are actually binding occurences of the variables for the pattern matching construct (in particular for the return clause). Your code is actually the same as

```
Definition plus_O_2 := 
(fix F (m : mynat) : m == plus m O :=
    match m as m0 with
      | O as m2 => myeq_refl O : m2 == plus m2 O
      | S x as m2 => ((match F x in (p == q) return (S p == S q) with
                        | myeq_refl x0 => myeq_refl (S x0)
                      end) : m2 == plus m2 O)
    end) : forall n : mynat, n == plus n O.
```

where I renamed the name of the variables in the inner match.

Now the constructor `myeq_refl x` is by construction of type `x == x` which should also be `p == q` so in that branch, it is enough to build a term of type `(S p == S q)[x/p, x/q]` (where brackets denote substitution), that is of type `S x == S x`. Since `myeq_refl` is the only constructor of this inductive type, you are done with this match once you have provided such a witness.

Comment: I see, so `myeq_refl (S x0)` has type `S x0 == S x0`, which is included in `S p == S q`. But then, at the same time, the type specifier also says that the return type is `m2 == plus m2 O` which is `S x == plus (S x) O` which again is `S x == S (plus x O)` (which is also included in `S p == S q`). This is different from `myeq_refl (S x0)`'s type `S x0 == S x0`, but Coq accepts it. Does this mean that Coq passes the type checker since both are included in the more broader type `S p == S q`, although the two types seem to not be immediately equivalent?

Comment: In other words, is this what's happening? 1. There exists some `p`,`q` where `S p == S q` matches the type of `myeq_refl (S x0)`. 2. `match F x in (p == q) return (S p == S q)` states that the return type is `S x == S (plus x O)`, and there also exists some `p`,`q` where `S p == S q` matches the type. 3. Although the type of `myeq_refl (S x0)` and `S x == S (plus x O)` do not match, it is enough for Coq's type checker if There exists some `p`,`q` (for each type) where `S p == S q` matches each of the types.

Comment: yes. In the point 3), it is indeed enough because `F x` will have to compute to a canonical form of the type `_ == _` for the match to reduce, and the only canonical form in that type is  of the shape `myeq_refl _`.